# Inverse matrix’s eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It’s from the book “Linear Algebra and its Applications” by Gilbert Strang, page 260.

$$(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2+A^3+\ldots$$

Nonnegative matrix $A$ has the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1<1$.

Then, the book says $(I-A)^{-1}$ has the same eigenvector, with eigenvalue $1/(1-\lambda_1)$.

Why? Is there any other formulas between inverse matrix and eigenvalue that I don’t know?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are looking at a single eigenvector $v$ only, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $A$ just acts as the scalar $\lambda$, and *any* reasonable expression in $A$ acts on $v$ as the same expression in $\lambda$. This works for expressions $I-A$ (really $1-A$, so it acts as $1-\lambda$), its inverse $(I-A)^{-1}$, in fact for any rational function of $A$ (if well defined; this is where you need $\lambda_1<1$) and even for $\exp A$.

Answer (score 208):

A matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ if and only if $A^{-1}$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^{-1}$. To see this, note that
$$A\mathbf{v} = \lambda\mathbf{v} \implies A^{-1}A\mathbf{v} = \lambda A^{-1}\mathbf{v}\implies A^{-1}\mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{v}$$

If your matrix $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $I-A$ has eigenvalue $1 - \lambda$ and therefore $(I-A)^{-1}$ has eigenvalue $\frac{1}{1-\lambda}$.

Comment: OMG! That's brilliant! Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question! How can I show that I-A has an eigenvalue 1-$\lambda_{1}$?

Comment: Let $\mathbf{v}$ be an eigenvector of $A$ under $\lambda$. Then $$(I-A)\mathbf{v} = I\mathbf{v} - A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v} - \lambda\mathbf{v} = (1-\lambda)\mathbf{v}$$

Comment: Let $\vec{v}$ be an eigenvector of $A$ Then $(I-A)\vec{v}=I\vec{v}-A\vec{v}=\vec{v}-\lambda\vec{v}=(1-\lambda)\vec{v}$

Comment: Why I can't accept your answer? The box keeps saying me to wait in 6 minutes.

Comment: @EuYu Hope I can revive this post for a quick question. What happened when going from the second implication to the third in your answer. To be more clear, how did u go from $A^{-1}A\mathbf{v} = \lambda A^{-1}\mathbf{v}$ to $A^{-1}\mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{v}$? Is it because we know that $A^{-1}\mathbf{v}=\lambda^{-1}\mathbf{v}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @S.Crim We have $\lambda A^{-1}\mathbf{v} = A^{-1}A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}$. We know that $\lambda \neq 0$ since $A$ is invertible, so we can divide through by $\lambda$ to get the desired result.

Comment: @EuYu Perfect, thanks alot!

Comment: @EuYu, I would also like to revive this post and ask for a precision for the point of Charlie Shuffler: If we have $\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{A}\textbf{v} = \lambda \textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{v}$, this could also be written $\textbf{I}\textbf{v} = \lambda \textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{v}$, correct? Shouldn't we write then $\frac{1}{\lambda}\textbf{I}\textbf{v} = \lambda \textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{v}$ ("matrix = matrix"). In other words how can we get rid of  $\textbf{I}$ to have at end "vector = matrix"? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @ecjb You have $I\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}$ because the identity matrix, by definition, does nothing to the vector it acts on. It's just like how you can write $a = 1\times a$ for any real number $a$. A matrix acting on a vector returns a vector, not a matrix. More precisely, the product of a $m\times n$ matrix with a $n\times k$ matrix returns a $m \times k$ matrix. A (column) vector is just an $n\times 1$ matrix, so there's no contradiction here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations @EuYu!

Comment: should be accepted answer!